# Vuex 4 Modules can't use global axios property

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vuejs3, vuex-modules

I have a Vue3 (without Typescript) app running Vuex 4.0.0.

I'm trying to set up a simple GET request in one of my store modules using axios, however I'm getting a `Cannot read property of 'get' of undefined` when I try to do it via an action called in one of my components, however if I call `this.$axios` from the component it works fine. For some reason, my modules can't use `this.$axios`, while elsewhere in the app I can.

I've declared `$axios` as a `globalProperty` in my `main.js` file.

```js
// main.js

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { router } from "./router";
import { store } from "./store";
import axios from "axios";

const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router);
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;

app.mount("#app");
```

And the store module looks like this (simplified for the purposes of this question):

```js
// store/modules/example.js

const state = () => ({
  message: ""
});

const mutations = {
  getMessage(state, payload) {
    state.message = payload;
  }
};

const actions = {
  async setMessage(commit) {
    this.$axios.get("example.com/endpoint").then(response => {
      commit("setMessage", response.message);
    });
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

The main `store/index.js` that's getting imported in `main.js` above looks like this:

```js
// store/index.js

import "es6-promise";
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import example from "./modules/example";

export const store = createStore({ modules: { example } });
```

In the component, I have the following:

```js
// MyComponent.vue

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      message: "example/getMessage"
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      getMessage: "example/setMessage"
    })
  }
};
```

And a simple button with `@click="getMessage"`. Clicking this button, however, returns `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, but if I copy/paste the `setMessage` action into a component method, it works just fine.

Is there a way for me to expose `this.$axios` to the store files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not the ideal solution, as I would've preferred to have my `$axios` instance available globally with a single declaration in the mount file, it's probably the next best thing.

I made a `lib/axiosConfig.js` file that exports an axios instance with some custom axios options, and I just import that one instance in every module that needs it.

```js
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL= import.meta.env.DEV ? "http://localhost:8000": "example.com";
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
// etc...

export const $axios = axios.create();
```

And in whatever module I need `$axios` in, I just `import { $axios } from "./lib/axiosConfig`. It's not perfect as I mentioned, since I do still have to import it in every module, but it's close enough as far as I can see, and has the added benefit of using the same axios config everywhere by just importing this file.